# Use django FormWizard step data as initial data of the next step

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I have a Django `SessionWizardView` which on the first step, collects a person's details, then provides an option to add another person's details which will be associated with this person.

If that option is selected I want to be able to use the information entered as the initial data for the next step. My initial attempt at setting the initial data looked like this;

```
def get_form_initial(self, step, **kwargs):
    initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
    current_step = self.storage.current_step

    if int(current_step) > 0 or int(step) > 0:
        data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
        initial.update(data)

    return initial
```

But this seems inconsistent & lead to some recursive calls. So I've tried to set the initial step's data as an attribute of the class in order to use that;

```
class SignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'wizard_form.html'
    form_list = form_list
    condition_dict = cond_dict
    model = Entrant

    def get_form_initial(self, step, **kwargs):
        initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
        try:
            current_step = int(self.storage.current_step)
        except TypeError:
            current_step = None

        if current_step > 0 and int(step) > 0:
            try:
                initial.update(self.main_entrant_data)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

        return initial

    def process_step(self, form):
        data = self.get_form_step_data(form)
        if isinstance(form, MainEntrantForm):
            self.main_entrant_data = data
        return data
```

However the data returned here includes the step in the dictionary keys so to use this you'd need to modify all the dict keys; `<QueryDict: {u'0-last_name': [u'blah'], u'0-title': [u'MR'], u'submit': [u''], u'0-dob_year': [u'1984'], ... }>`. So I've written an addition to modify the keys, but the values seem to end up in a list;

```
def get_form_initial(self, step, **kwargs):
    initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
    try:
        current_step = int(self.storage.current_step)
    except TypeError:
        current_step = None

    if current_step > 0 and int(step) > 0:
        try:
            step_data = self.main_entrant_data.copy()
            for k, v in step_data.iteritems():
                new_key = re.sub(u'0-', u'', k)
                step_data[new_key] = step_data.pop(k)
                step_data[new_key] = v
            initial.update(step_data)
            print step_data
        except AttributeError, e:
            print e

    return initial
```

`step_data` is then equal to `<QueryDict: {u'last_name': [u'Walker'], u'house': [u'12'], ...`

And if I leave out that line `step_data[new_key] = v` then the values are all list types; `<QueryDict: {u'last_name': [[[u'Walker']]], u'house': [[u'12']], ...`

Answer (score 0):

My current resolution to collecting this data from the first form is to create my own dictionary rather than using `form.data`;

```
def process_step(self, form):
    data = self.get_form_step_data(form)
    if isinstance(form, FreeCycleEntrantForm):
        entrant_data = dict()
        for k, v in data.iteritems():
            entrant_data[k] = v
        self.main_entrant_data = entrant_data
    return data
```